# Is there a Clearpath Husky simulator for Jade?

Tags: husky

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS (jade) in ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS.
I was going through the Clearpath tutorials to better understand ROS. Clearpath has done a great job. I was following the instructions in "ROS 101: Drive a Husky" tutorial. The instructions said to run the following two commands:
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-husky-desktop
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-husky-simulator
I replaced "indigo" with "jade" to match the package I have installed.
The install cound not fine the packages.
"E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-husky-desktop"
and
"E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-husky-simulator".
Did I make a mistake or does these packages not exist for jade? I there anything I can do to resolve this problem? Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224420/is-there-a-clearpath-husky-simulator-for-jade?/) by [Skip](https://answers.ros.org/users/25650/skip/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seem like no.

At [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/husky_simulator), there is no jade tab. Also in [github repo](https://github.com/husky/husky_simulator), there seems no jade branch.

And finally, you can check [debbuild page for jade](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/jade.html) in the future for state of necessary packages.

Maybe you should wait a little.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should be possible to check out the source code for the husky simulator from github and build it locally; but that process can be a bit of a big task for a beginner. (I think one of the later Clearpath tutorials may cover this)

If you're interested in a Jade release, waiting is not the best option. Instead, I'd suggest that you check the issue tracker on github to see if there's an issue requesting a Jade release, and if there isn't, create one.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1